# How to purchase a realm on the Switch

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, nintendo-switch, nintendo-eshop, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

I am thinking about buying a realm, but I am wondering if it if possible to use the Nintendo eShop to get one.

**Is this possible to do via buying the coins, or is there something else that needs to be done?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to use your coins from buying digital games on eshop to purchase the Minecraft Coins to purchase the Realm Subscription.